# Not working following code

Tags: 2010, visual-studio

webtemp file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Templates xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint">
  <Template Name="MyReed" ID="10001">
    <Configuration ID="0" Title="MyReed" RootWebOnly="True"  
                   ProvisionClass="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PortalProvisioningProvider"
                   ProvisionData="Template\\SiteTemplates\\MyReed\\xml\\SubSite.xml"
                   ProvisionAssembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
                   Type="0"   
                   Hidden="FALSE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/CPVW.gif" Description="MyReed" DisplayCategory="SharePoint Customizations" >
    </Configuration>

  </Template>
```

SubSite file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<portal xmlns="PortalTemplate.xsd">
  <web name="Home"
        siteDefinition="MyReed1#0"
        displayName="MyReed"
        description="MyReed" >
    <webs>
      <web name="SubSite1"
        siteDefinition="MyReed2#0"
        displayName="Sub Site"
        description="Custom Demo Company sub site." />
    </webs>
  </web>
</portal>
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify this question. What is not working? When, and Where do you see this message? What was the expected result?

Comment: can you explain whats the issue

Comment: when i create site collection ie display message "webpage does not display".

Comment: Try the setup using OOTB site definitions, ie: STS#0 instead of your MyReet1#0 defintion.

Comment: @JamesLove Not working.again same problem.

Comment: Try removing the TEMPLATE\\ bit in your ProvisionData element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question contains very little information on what the actual problem is or what you're trying to accomplish. Could you provide more information on what it is you're trying to do here, maybe add some more code?

One thing that doesn't add up in the little code you provided is the fact that you create a template/definition with name MyReed and then try to create a web structure that points to two different templates/definitions MyReed1 and MyReed2. Are the MyReed1 and MyReed2 templates/definitions available? If so, please provide details about these templates too.

~Mark

Comment: I want to make subsites in sitedefinition named "MyReed".There are no any templates named MyReed 1&2.is that wrong.what i have to use instead of that?

Comment: What templates do you want to use for your subsites?

Comment: Also, you tagged your question with 2010, but refer to Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing version 12.0.0.0. What SharePoint version are you using? If it's 2010, you probably want to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c

Comment: I want to use teamsite.

Comment: Ya.Version was the problem.Now Solved. Thanx.